# Multiple background images casuses error in Safari

Tags: html, css, safari, webkit

I'm trying to style the body element with two images.

```
background: url(bg2.png) repeat-x, url(bg1.png) repeat;
```

The problem is that Safari generates an error in the console, complaining about how it can't find the image file which is the last to be specified in the code above.

The background images still display correct.

Any thoughts on why this is accouring?

Comment: Did you try putting both url first (same line), and in a different line the other properties? I could be wrong, but multiple backgrounds follow a certain syntax, don´t they?

Comment: Yeah, the syntax is a bit wonky but Chrome doesn't complain about the code. Just thought if there's a bug or some work around for Safari.

Comment: I can´t find any comments on safari bugs for multiple backgrounds... it´s been supported by it for a while http://caniuse.com/multibackgrounds

Comment: Perhaps you need to specify the position, try `background: url(bg2.png) top left repeat-x, url(bg1.png) top left repeat;`

Answer (score 2):

To answer the question above, your syntax is incorrect.

```
body{
background-image: url("../img/logo.jpg"), url("../img/background.png");
background-repeat:no-repeat, repeat-y;
background-position: right 30px, right top;
background-attachment:fixed, scroll;
background-color:#ffffff;
color:#000000;
}
```

Note: the first image will have the highest stacking order.

Now for my question related to multiple background images. Checking my error logs, I've noticed errors for the above background images. I tried to fix this by using absolute URLs to no avail. I can only assume these 404s are caused by older versions of IE.  Anyone else using multiple background images notice this in their error logs?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried it using background-image instead of background?

Comment: `background-image` *and* `background-repeat`, that is.

Comment: I broke `background` shortkut into `background-image`, `background-repeat` and `background-position` and it resolved my issue across versions of Safari.